# Notifications in ASP.NET Core client for IdentityServer v4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3, asp.net-core-1.0, identityserver4

In IdentityServer 3 I used the `SecurityTokenValidated` event on the Notifications to build up my own identity with names and claims. For example I store the `access_token` to later access n API with a resource owner workflow like this:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
AuthenticationType = "oidc",

// ...

Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
    {
        var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
          n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
          "name",
          ClaimTypes.Role);
        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));
    }
}
}
```

In IdentityServer 4 for ASP.NET Core is not Notifications property.
I can see that there a lot of claims automatically generated but I don't get the `access_token` nor the username of the identity is set automatically

My current configuration of the client in ASP.NET Core looks like this

```
   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",
            Authority = identityServerUri,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ClientId = clientId,
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope =
            {
                "openid profile email warehouseapi"
            },
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SaveTokens = true,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
        });
```

What is the intended way in IdentityServer 4 to make this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TickedReceived` event to transform claims:

```
        var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            ...
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                // get access token
                OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
                {
                    // transform claims
                    var access_token = ctx.Ticket.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
```

Also you don't need save tokens as claims, because when you set `SaveTokens` to true, tokens are automatically saved in the authentication properties. To get a token, you can use `HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("<token name>")`.

Comment: thx the events works but in my asp core project there is no GetTokenAsync Method ad the HttpContext.Authentication

Comment: Try to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` using.

Comment: Where do you want to get token? If in `TickedReceived` event, you can't get token by this way, in this case you can use `var token = ctx.Ticket.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");`.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not related to IdentityServer4. It is rather more of a difference between the Authentication middlewares in the OWIN and AspNetCore variants.

These notifications are now more correctly named `Events`

you can do something similar using:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",

    Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:3308/",
    ClientId = "hybrid",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
    SaveTokens = true,

    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async n =>
        {

        }
    }
});
```

You can find all the nice events [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events).